# Why does as(spdf, "owin") throw an error 'spatstat.options' is not an exported object from 'namespace:spatstat'

Tags: r, geospatial, r-sf

From this book [here](https://mgimond.github.io/Spatial/app1-1.html#ref-sf)

```
library(maptools)
s.owin <- as(s.sp, "owin")
class(s.owin)
```

should work, but it does not and throws the error `'spatstat.options' is not an exported object from 'namespace:spatstat'`. `spatstat.options()` exists and works fine (to me):

```
spatstat.options()
# $areainter.polygonal
# [1] FALSE
#
# $checksegments
# [1] TRUE
# ...
```

I use the latest version of statspat: `packageVersion("spatstat")` gives `2.0.1`. RStudio does not show any dependent package for the update process:

```
x <- installed.packages()
x[grepl("spatstat",x[,"Depends"]),"Package"]
         spatstat     spatstat.core     spatstat.geom   spatstat.linnet 
       "spatstat"   "spatstat.core"   "spatstat.geom" "spatstat.linnet"
```

`p.ppp <- as(p.sp, "ppp") # Create ppp object` throws the same error...

---

Reproducible example:

```
library(sp)
grd <- sp::GridTopology(c(1,1), c(1,1), c(10,10))
polys <- as(grd, "SpatialPolygons")
centroids <- sp::coordinates(polys)
x <- centroids[,1]
y <- centroids[,2]
z <- 1.4 + 0.1*x + 0.2*y + 0.002*x*x
spdf <- sp::SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(polys,
                                     data = data.frame(x=x,
                                                       y=y,
                                                       z=z,
                                                       row.names=row.names(polys)))

library(raster)
plot(spdf)

library(sf)
spsf <- st_as_sf(spdf)
plot(spsf$geometry)
plot(spsf)

library(maptools)
library(spatstat)
s.owin <- as(spdf, "owin") # calls as.owin.SpatialPolygons(from) but to me it is not clear why and I can't debug here...
# Fehler: 'spatstat.options' is not an exported object from 'namespace:spatstat'
spatstat.options()
```

Comment: The 'spatstat' package has been updated a couple of days ago. Could it be the cause ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I think it is up to date, `packageVersion("spatstat")` gives 2.0.1.

Comment: Yes, but maybe a package depending a 'spatstat' has not been updated accordingly.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I had to update R and everything else. Strange... See my answer below. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although RStudio told me, all packages were up to date, the problem continued to exist.
The solution was a full update of R and all packages. The process **on Windows**:

- Run `installr::update()`from Rgui.exe (in \R\R-4.0.4\bin\x64).
- Update Windows environment variable `R_LIBS`the the new \R\R-4.0.4\library.
- update Rprofile.site in \R\R-4.0.4\etc and make sure there is only one `.libPaths()`. (There has to be a line `.libPaths("C:/R/R-4.0.4/library")` or just add it.)
- Check if there are pending package updates in RStudio

Answer (score 1):

just had this problem and can confirm that updating packages was the fix. I actually couldn't follow your instructions (I'm not too savvy) but the below simple code worked:

first- restart R so any preloaded packages are cleared and can be updated

```
    # list of packages where an update is available
    old.packages()
    
    # update all available packages
    update.packages()
    
    # update, without prompts for permission/clarification
    update.packages(ask = FALSE)
```

Comment: You are working on Windows? Are you using Rgui or RStudio? How did you restart R?

Comment: @Christoph Windows & R studio and to restart R i just quit the program and reopened it lol